# Python/Pandas - Creating a new Column showing Average of only the Largest value for each group

Tags: python, pandas, average

I am working with a dataset, and am trying to create a new column that will show the average number per ID label in a row, but only based off the last row, which is the largest number in the ID group. Example is below.

My current dataset:

```
    ID      Date        DaysInDuration
    NCA   11/19/2019        31                 
    NCA   12/19/2019        62              
    NCA   12/19/2019        92             
    NCA   1/19/2020         120 * Last Row
    DTT   11/19/2019        31                 
    DTT   12/19/2019        62              
    DTT   12/19/2019        92             
    DTT   1/19/2020         100 * Last Row
```

And I'm trying to create this:

```
    ID      Date        DaysInDuration          AverageDurColumn *is only based off last row numb 
    NCA   11/19/2019        31                        30
    NCA   12/19/2019        62                        30
    NCA   12/19/2019        92                        30
    NCA   1/19/2020         120 * Last Row            30
    DTT   11/19/2019        31                        25
    DTT   12/19/2019        62                        25
    DTT   12/19/2019        92                        25
    DTT   12/29/2020        100 * Last Row            25
```

Thank you to all who can assist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple answer for you:

`df['answer'] = df.groupby('ID')['DaysInDuration'].transform(lambda x: x.max()/x.count())`

I simply transformed your question into `"How do I take the maximum value per ID and divide it by the number of records that ID has?"`

1.First Group by ID

2.Get the Max Value for Each ID

3.Divide by the number of records for that ID

4.Use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to apply it to the rows

```
    ID        Date  DaysInDuration  answer
0  NCA  11/19/2019              31      30
1  NCA  12/19/2019              62      30
2  NCA  12/19/2019              92      30
3  NCA   1/19/2020             120      30
4  DTT  11/19/2019              31      25
5  DTT  12/19/2019              62      25
6  DTT  12/19/2019              92      25
7  DTT   1/19/2020             100      25
```

Comment: Thank you, I like your answer, it worked, but I also got a message: ```SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead``` Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `GroupBy.transform` here with `last` and `size`:

```
grp = df.groupby('ID')
last = grp['DaysInDuration'].transform('last')
n = grp['DaysInDuration'].transform('size')

df['AverageDurColumn'] = last / n

    ID        Date  DaysInDuration  AverageDurColumn
0  NCA  11/19/2019              31              30.0
1  NCA  12/19/2019              62              30.0
2  NCA  12/19/2019              92              30.0
3  NCA   1/19/2020             120              30.0
4  DTT  11/19/2019              31              25.0
5  DTT  12/19/2019              62              25.0
6  DTT  12/19/2019              92              25.0
7  DTT   1/19/2020             100              25.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby`, `apply`, and `merge`:

```
new_df = df.merge(
  df
  .groupby(['ID'])
  .apply(lambda x: x['DaysInDuration'].max() / len(x['DaysInDuration'])
  .reset_index(),
  how='outer',
  on='ID',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

df["AverageDurColumn"]=np.where(df["ID"].ne(df["ID"].shift(-1)), df["DaysInDuration"], 0)

df=df.set_index("ID")
df["AverageDurColumn"]=df.groupby("ID")["AverageDurColumn"].mean()
df=df.reset_index()
```

Outputs:

```py
    ID        Date  DaysInDuration  AverageDurColumn
0  NCA  11/19/2019              31                30
1  NCA  12/19/2019              62                30
2  NCA  12/19/2019              92                30
3  NCA   1/19/2020             120                30
4  DTT  11/19/2019              31                25
5  DTT  12/19/2019              62                25
6  DTT  12/19/2019              92                25
7  DTT   1/19/2020             100                25
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution in one shot:

```
df["AverageDurColumn"]=df.groupby("ID").DaysInDuration.transform(lambda s: s.iloc[-1]/s.size)
```

Comment: thanks @Kantal!  The numbers seemed a bit off compared to @MattR's answer, but that may have to do with my implementation of it on my dataset.